# What is the solution of request entity too large

Tags: php

I want to add files more than 1mb through tnymice editor. If files size is less than 1mb then code is work will but if size exceed 1mb request entity to large error occurred. Please tell what is the solution of this error. I don't have knowledge about this error. Here is my php_ini file code. please help me.

```
memory_limit = 20000M;
max_execution_time = 10000;
upload_max_filesize = 20000M;
max_allowed_packet = 500M;
post_max_size =  100M;
```

Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource /phpcode_class.php does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a 413 Request Entity Too Large error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the upload.maxsize in the config (http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager:upload.maxsize).

If you use some plugin for file uploads, you should read its configuration.